# set cache ttl for cloudfront images with query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-s3, caching, amazon-cloudfront

I am using S3 with cloudfront to deliver the static content. The only issue is with images cache TTL when I use query string in my images.

For example

```
https://cloudfronturl/static_images/banners/web/Slider-1.jpeg?format=auto
```

For this I am getting issue of

> Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy

I have already setup cache policy in my cloudfront and it is working if I request without query string

for example

```
https://cloudfronturl/static_images/banners/web/Slider-1.jpeg
```

How can I fix the cache issue. Query string is required because I want images in different format and size for different place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few options in Cloudfront for whitelisting or allowing/blocking queryStrings to optimize cache.

- Don't forward query strings to the origin at all. If you don't
  forward query strings, CloudFront doesn't cache based on the query string
  parameters.
- Forward query strings to the origin, and cache based on all
  parameters in the query string.
- Forward query strings to the origin, and cache based on specified
  parameters in the query string

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/QueryStringParameters.html

If the above doesn't work you can try adding a new custom header to cache policy with cache-contorl header https://i.imgur.com/rvzgDkh.png

Comment: I already knew that but even adding that there is same for query string.

Comment: are you able to share the cache policies screenshot or source code?

Comment: I have fixed it. I have to set custom header as well. Not only allowing query string will work.

Comment: can you add the answer so others can get the help as well

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/rvzgDkh.png add this in your answer and mention you need to create a custom cache policy. I will accept your answer then there will no need for new answer.